# Why haven't we designed a computer to directly execute high level programming?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I always thought that computers nowadays are already programmed to directly execute high-level programming, but apparently not. Is there any specific reason why we haven't done that yet? Any cons of high-level programming.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine

Comment: ARM experimented with HW support for Java bytecode for a while, but good software JIT was faster so Jazelle-capable CPUs died out.  See my answer on a related question: [Have programming languages driven hardware development?](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8890)

Comment: *Any cons of high level programming.* No, not because of cons of writing programs in HLLs, only cons of trying to build HW to execute them directly when you could just have software compile to easy-to-execute machine code.

Comment: HLL needs a parser more often than not. Consider a `while () {}` loop, this statement spans multiple lines and embeds other code. It seems obvious that any approach on executing it will lead back to what we are doing now: compiling to simple, standalone, instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm by no means a CS expert, but from my experience dealing with different layers of a computer system, layers of abstraction are very important to enable a collaborative development environment. For instance, when you want to implement a neural network, would you prefer implement everything manually, or use an existing library? Having different layers make systems more secure, debugging easier, and better specialization in development. One can specialize in a higher level API and don't have to worry about the lower level implementation.

When you say a computer that directly executes high-level language, keep in mind that any computer is still composed of transistors, meaning everything would still have to be translated into binary operations. Having a completely packaged system (from high-level directly to hardware) vs having a layered structure (write a high-level program and compile it to instruct the hardware) is much more [inefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_language_computer_architecture#Disadvantages).

Comment: Wow this was very clear to understand, thank you very much!

Comment: One also typically has caching at the different abstraction layers, so some of the work of translating from the most abstract format to the most specific format is done once for multiple uses. Even a conventional processor itself decodes/translates instructions from an in-memory format to a typically less dense and more specialized internal format, sometimes even caching these translations (µop caches) to reduce translation overhead.

Answer (score 3):

*This calls for speculation and over simplification, so that is what I will do*

What you describe is an interpreted language, and the question is why are we not running hardware interpreters?

The rational is simply it is more **cost efficient** (both calculated in both silcon area and in Watt / useful work) to make a hardware architecture suitable for implementation in silicon and then create an advanced optimizing compiler which translates to this architecture than create the same logic in silicon to interpret the high level code.

Another argument not to do it is **security**, hardware development cycles are long and it isn't even possible to release an updated version of the processor after massproduction, interpreters are notorious for being vulnerable with security problems on malformed inputs .